# Android Compose - Align center one composable only in Column?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In Compose, you can align center all composables in a Column widget by doing the following:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
        Text(
                text = "First item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
                text = "Second item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
                text = "Third item",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
}
```

However, what if I only want to center the first composable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for you

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "First item",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
        Text(
            text = "Second item",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth()
        )
        Text(
            text = "Third item",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
```

[image: Sample Render]